# Disaster recovery for TFS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, backup, disaster-recovery

I am using Team foundation server 2012. The TFS is installed in a windows 8 PC. For TFS database I am using SQL server 2008 R2. As a disaster recovery plan I take full backup of **tfs_configuration** (I think this is the only database used by TFS other than each database for collection) and backup of all the collection database(One database for each collection).I have taken backup of SQL database using SQL backup command. But I don't whether the backup alone will be helpful in case of DR.

Now in case of disaster recovery(hardware and OS crash) I have to shift the TFS to another new PC. I think simply installing all the softwares(like tfs,visual studio,sql server) and restoring the database will not work. As there will be some changes such as computer name etc.

So how can I recover from DR quickly? What should be the plan(including how and what data to backup)  and how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

The ALM Rangers publish a TFS Planning Guide which has a section on how to approach DR with TFS: http://vsarplanningguide.codeplex.com/

For DR it expects you to restore to a machine with the same name.  If you want to move TFS to a different machine, the recommended approach is to detach the Team Project Collections from within TFS Admin Console, then re-attach on a different TFS Instance on a different machine.

Comment: What about other settings in tfs_configuration ? Does it work if i restore tfs_configuration  of one pc to another?

Comment: If you want to completely recreate the TFS environment on another PC, you can restore the TFS Backups then make sure to run the tfsconfig changeserverid command.  See this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2006/10/17/creating-a-new-server-from-an-old-one-beware-of-the-instanceid.aspx

Comment: After installing TFS power tool from http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f  .I didn't get database backup tool option added to TFS server administrative console. My TFS product version is 11.0.50727.1 . What is the reason for  database backup tool option not being added?